# undefined method `gravatar_url' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a rails 4 app that works with a brand new pg database, after 20 users are created I begin to get this error

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gravatar_url' for
>   nil:NilClass)

Here is the user.rb model:

```
def gravatar_url
  stripped_email = email.strip
  downcased_email= stripped_email.downcase
  hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(downcased_email)

  "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}?r=x"
end
```

And here is the index.html.erb

```
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
<div class="status">
  <div class ="row">
    <div class="span1">
      <%= image_tag status.user.gravatar_url %>
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
      <strong><%= status.user.full_name %></strong>
      <p><%= status.content %></p>
      <div class="meta">
        <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at) + " ago" , status %>
        <span class="admin">
          | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_status_path(status) %> |
          <%= link_to "Delete", status, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are                     you sure you want to delete this status?"} %>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I drop the db and start from scratch with rake db:migrate it works just fine, but once I hit 20 users, things begin to go wrong and the app throws an exception.

Here is the Statuses Controller

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_status, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]


  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /statuses/new
  def new
    @status = Status.new
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = current_user.statuses.new(status_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /statuses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
    @status = current_user.statuses.find(params[:id])

    if params[:status] && params[:status].has_key?(:user_id)
      params[:status].delete(:user_id) 
    end  


    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update(status_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_status
      @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def status_params
      params.require(:status).permit(:name, :content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Here is status class:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true,
                      length:{ minimum: 2 }

  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

And here is the user class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true

  validates :last_name, presence: true

  validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                           uniqueness: true,
                           format: {
                             with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\Z/,
                             message: 'must be formatted correctly.'
                           }

  has_many :statuses
 end
```

And the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :profile_name, 
                                                            :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:statuses) { |u| u.permit(:user_id)}
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show the controller?

Comment: and also the user and status classes. You see, user beeing nil is causing the problem.

Comment: @HélioSantos I added the requested classes/controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of the statuses retrieved via `Status.all` isn't associated with a user. Your view is throwing an error because it's finally trying to access the `gravatarl_url` convenience method on `status.user`, but because the status has no user, it throws a `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'gravatar_url' for nil:NilClass):` exception.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
Status.find(1).user.nil? == false
Status.find(2).user.nil? == false
Status.find(3).user.nil? == true # no associated user
Status.find(4).user.nil? == false
```

When you assign `Status.all` to the `@statuses` instance variable, it will include all four statuses – *including* the third status, which has no associated user. When looping over `@statuses` in your view, you'll receive an error when the third status is looped:

```
# first pass
status.user # found

# second pass
status.user # found

# third pass
status.user # NilClass exception is thrown, causing loop to exit
```

To identify which statuses have no associated user, run the following Arel query:

```
Status.joins("left join users on users.status_id = statuses.id").where("users.status_id is null")
#=> [#<Status id: 3>]
```

To resolve the error, simply associate a user with the statuses which have no user:

```
status = Status.find(3)
user = User.create
status.user = user # associates `user` with `status`

Status.joins("left join users on users.status_id = statuses.id").where("users.status_id is null")
#=> [] # all statuses are now associated with a user
```

**UPDATE**:

To conditionally destroy the parent in the event that the `has_one` child is destroyed, you can implement a series of callbacks within your child model (`User`) that will execute when a user is destroyed:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ... existing logic

    before_destroy :find_parent
    after_destroy :destroy_orphaned_parent

    def find_parent
         @parent = self.parent
    end

    def destroy_orphaned_parent
        if @parent.children.length == 0
            @parent.destroy
        end  
    end
end
```

Comment: The status has no user because I left a delete option WITHOUT deleting the statuses for the newly deleted User. THANK YOU SIR. The 20 users was arbitrary, and had zero to do with the bug. I'll edit this with my final answer tomorrow.

Comment: See my updated answer for a solution that will automatically destroy a status when the associated user is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `status.user` returns nil, which means that there's no `user_id` property is `nil` (or `NULL`, in the database).

Another option may be that the user no longer exists, but I believe that would throw an error if you tried to look it up.

Comment: So what occurs that would throw a functioning app into a non functioning one after 20 users? Why nil now?